# What does the piece of paper in chapter 222 say?

Tags: nisekoi

On the fourth page of Nisekoi chapter 222, there is a page that shows a stick figure drawing of a girl and boy together in the middle with other girls on top and it's in Japanese.

[image: chapter 222, page 4]

What does it say and is it important to the Nisekoi story line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the piece of paper is very important to the story line. In chapter 220, you'll be able to see what is written on the piece of paper, but here is what it says.

SPOILER

> The prince puts the ring on their fingers, then two angels
>  appeared.
>
>  Angel: "Poor prince, let's reunite him with the princess."
>
>  Original: And then, the prince and the princess were brought to heaven.
>  The prince and the princess lived in heaven happily ever after.
>
>  Raku (MC) made some changes and it is now like this: Then, the princess
>  was revived by the angels. The prince and the princess lived happily
>  ever after.

The translation might be a bit different because I translated it myself, but that is what it says and it's the last page of the drawing book. It made Chitoge and Kosaki remember their past. This is shown in the rest of chapters 220 and 221.

Hope this helps.